# Dynamic div height using css tables doesn't work in IE9 or IE10

Tags: css, internet-explorer, cross-browser, internet-explorer-9, internet-explorer-10

Consider the following fiddle: http://fiddle.jshell.net/du8Ws/

The intention is to have the bottom div (red) resize to consume the remaining vertical space when the size of the first div (blue) changes.

When run in chrome or IE11, observe that if the user clicks the toggle size button, the blue div will change size and the red div will change size accordingly such that the blue, green and red divs are all contained within the same height (equal to the pink divs height for reference).

When run in IE9 or IE10, the red divs height will be larger than it should by an amount equal to the height of the blue div.

How would one change this such that it works in IE9 and IE10 the same way that it works in Chrome using only css (no javascript!)?

Note that it is important that the red div has a non-zero height.

pstenstrm has provided a good solution that appears to display correctly, however the actual height of the red div in this case is equal to its children (the text), rather than the remaining available space of its parent, while the inner and outer heights take up more space (due to the padding/margin). I intend to embed a control in this red div which requires the height to be correct.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When I removed `display:table` property from Table class. It started working and pushing the data downwards without increasing height of whole container. as expected behavior. But the red patch is not shown up.

Below is the `CSS`

```
.table {
    background-color: #FFFF00;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: The red div does not have any height in this case which is important behavior. I will update the original question to make this clearer.

Answer (score 0):

If the solution does not have to use tables you can use a combination of overflow, padding and negative margin to get this effect. It will also result in cleaner html.

The markup you need:

```
<div id="reference"></div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="first">First</div>
  <div class="second">Second</div>
  <div class="third">Third</div>
</div>
```

And the css:

```
#reference {
  background: pink;
  height: 300px;
  width: 50px;
  float: left;
}

.container {
  background: yellow;
  height: 300px;
  width: 50px;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.first {
  height: 50px;
  background: blue;
}

.first.big {
  height: 100px;
}

.second {
  background: green;
}

.third {
  background: red;
  padding: 0 0 999px;
  margin: 0 0 -999px;
}
```

The red div's padding will expand the background all the way down. And the containers `overflow: hidden;` will make sure it doesn't expand too far.

Comment: Thanks for the response. This is a good answer, however in this case the third div's height is not correct, even thought the background displays correctly in the example. The div's height is equal to its contents (i.e. the height of the text), while the inner and outer heights are both greater than 1000px. In the original example, the red div's height was 400px. My intended usage of this effect requires the div's height to be correct. I will make this clearer in the original question.